# How to validate catch block of a function in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have a basic stringify function that looks like this ->

```
export const stringify = <T>(value: T) => {
  try {
    return JSON.stringify(value);
  } catch(error){
    return ''
  }
}
```

I want to write a test that can cover the catch block of the function.
I've tried adding such a test ->

```
it('should be able to check for errors', async () => {
  await expect(stringify('')).rejects.toThrow()
})
```

But this test keeps throwing errors about the function not being a promise. The function isn't going into the catch block at all.

The main function isn't a promise so I can't use the promise functions of jest.

How do I test the catch block?

Comment: Your `stringify` function is not asynchronous, I think you can remove the `async` keyword and the `await` from your test.

Comment: That's how it was before. The thing is, I won't be able to use the '.rejects' without the function throwing a promise, right? How do I make it work?

Comment: As an async function it _doesn't_ reject, just as it wouldn't throw as a regular function - you **catch the error**.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `async/await` in this test. Also when there is an error you are returning `''` from `catch` block, meaning your function will not throw anything.

Something like will work for your case

```
it('should be able to check for errors', () => {
  expect(stringify(<error value>)).toBe('')
})
```

Comment: The function won't go into the catch block for any case that I can image and so I won't be able to cover that test case. What I wanted to ask is that is there any way to make the function go into the catch without changing its logic? I cant think of any <error value> for such a function.

Comment: If you pass an object which is cyclic, it will throw an exception.
Something like.

const x = {};
x.x = x;
stringify(x)

Answer (score 0):

Expect the function definition to Throw

```
const functionDef = () => {
    throw new TypeError("Error Message");
};

test("Test description", () => {  
  expect(functionDef).toThrow(TypeError);
  expect(functionDef).toThrow("Error Message");
});
```

Comment: Their implementation _doesn't_ throw...

Comment: Yes that's the issue. The function won't go into the catch block for any case that I can image and so I won't be able to cover that test case. What i wanted to ask is that is there any way to make the function go into the catch without changing its logic?